# Urllib giving fake proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, urllib, http-proxy

I test my proxies with this script and it gives many working but when i test the "working" proxies with an other proxy checker only a very little amount works.

Here is the part that's checking if the proxy works:

```
def process(self, task):
    global alive
    global dead
    global tested
    proxy = task
    log_msg = str("Trying HTTP proxy%21s " % proxy)

    cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
                urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj),
                urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
                urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy})
    )

    try:
        t1 = time.time()
        response = opener.open(test_url, timeout=timeout_value).read()
        tested += 1
        t2 = time.time()
    except Exception as e:
        log_msg += "%s " % fail_msg
        print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + log_msg)
        dead += 1
        tested += 1
        return None

    log_msg += ok_msg + "Response time: %d" % (int((t2-t1)*1000))
    print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + log_msg)
    text_file = open(out_filename, "a")
    text_file.write(proxy + "\r\n")
    text_file.close()
    alive += 1
```

Comment: Hello, I understand this is your first question on Stackoverflow so please first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit the above question and provide more context and the concrete technical issue you're running into. Thanks

Comment: all your test does is to download `test_url` through the proxy. It doesn't even check if the response has the page contents - for all effects all it tests is that the proxy returns something, could be an error page?